# Compare content of the ArrayList against Resultset

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, resultset

I have String ArrayList to compare against Resultset.

Ex: ArrayList Elements

```
ITM001
ITM002
ITM003
ITM004
```

Ex: Resultset 1

```
ITM001
ITM002
ITM003
ITM004
```

Contains all elements
return ArrayList Empty;

Ex: Resultset 2

```
ITM001
ITM002
ITM004
```

Missing ITM003
return ArrayList ITM003;

Ex: Resultset 3

```
ITM001
ITM002
```

Missing ITM003, ITM004
return ArrayList ITM003,ITM004;

> If Resultset does not contain all elements of Arraylist, those missing
>   elements must return as an ArrayList. Else return empty ArrayList.

This is what I tried.

```
public static ArrayList<String> checkStoreItems(String currentStore, ArrayList<String> stlist) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = DBConnection.conn();
        String sql = "select itemId from Store_Items where storeID=(select storeID from StoreMain where locationName=?)";
        Object []values ={currentStore}; 
        ResultSet res = DBHandller.getData(sql, conn, values);
        ArrayList<String> storelist = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(res.next()){
              String item = res.getString("itemId");
              for (int i = 0; i < stlist.size(); i++) {
                    if (item.contains(stlist.get(i))) {
                          continue;     
                    }else{
                          storelist.add(item);
                    }
              }

        }

        return null;

  }
```

Comment: What is the exact question for us?

Comment: Where `stlist` comes from?

Comment: I want to compare contents of Arraylist against ResultsSet. If resultset not contains any elements of Arraylist those missing element must return as Arraylist. How do I do this.

Comment: What is `stlist` ? Why don't you use `list.contains()` instead of looping ?

Comment: Updated original code. stlist is a method parameter. Arraylist with String elements.

Comment: @noob thankx for your suggestion. I completely forgot that. Im gonna try that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly ,  you can try something like this :

```
    public static ArrayList<String> checkStoreItems(String currentStore, 
                       ArrayList<String> stlist) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = DBConnection.conn();
    String sql = "select itemId from Store_Items where storeID=(select storeID from StoreMain where locationName=?)";
    Object []values = {currentStore}; 
    ResultSet res = DBHandller.getData(sql, conn, values);
    Set<String> storelist = new HashSet<String>();
    while(res.next()){
          String item = res.getString("itemId");
          storelist.add(item);
   }
    stlist.removeAll(storelist);
    return stlist;
 }
```

Comment: Thanx lot for your reply. But here what i want to do is, ArrayList compare against Resultset and add those missing elements of arraylist to new arraylist(storelist). But here gives the missing elements in the resultset.

Comment: wow. This is exactly what I was looking. Thnx lot. It works. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashSet`'s `removeAll` method to perform the operation. You will first need to put the elements from each source into a `HashSet`.

This avoids the need to loop over the entire `ArrayList` for every element in the `ResultSet` making it an O(n) operation, instead of O(n^2).

```
ArrayList<String> diffResultSet(Collection<String> coll, ResultSet resultSet, int column) {
    Set<String> collSet = new HashSet<String>(coll);
    Set<String> resultSetSet = new HashSet<String>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        resultSetSet.add(resultSet.getString(column));
    }
    collSet.removeAll(resultSetSet);
    return new ArrayList<String>(collSet);
}
```

Comment: Thanx lot for your solution. Never tried something like this before.. Ill try this out and let you know.